# How to return elements after building a list of nodes in python

Tags: python, linked-list, nodes

Suppose we have the Node class and b_list function:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, elm, nxt):
        self.elm = elm
        self.nxt = nxt
```

```
def b_list(first, end):
    if first>= end:
        return None 
    else:
        return Node(first, b_list(first+1, end))
```

How can I create the "showelm (h)" function to yield the elements in the linked list h.
For example:

```
print(list(showelm(b_list(0, 10))))
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: I want to print each nodes value, BenH answered my question, the problem is solved.

Comment: What was the issue? Do you know how to use loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not fully sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish with the last line of code there, but I assume you're trying to first create your linked list, and then print each nodes value in sequence afterwards?

```
def showelm(node):
    while node:
        print(node.elm)
        node = node.nxt

nodeval = b_list(0, 10)
showelm(nodeval)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for your help!